# Get any value from a column aggregated by other column and where the max date is selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, top-n

I'm an SQL novice and I have a table with the following columns

```
+-------+--------+----+----+
| email |  date  | IP | ID |
+-------+--------+----+----+
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT T.email,
       Max(T.date),
       T.ip     AS User_IP,
       T.id     AS ID

FROM LoginTable as T

WHERE (IP IS NOT NULL)

GROUP BY T.email
```

Of course this won't work because IP and ID are not in a (max) aggregate function. But I need that the IP matches the ID and the date, so I cannot use (max) in those columns because I would get results from different rows, and that's not an option.

To recap, I need:

- A single row per each unique email (hence the group by)
- The row selected is the one with the most recent date -> max(date)
- I need IP and ID to be from the same row as the row selected by max(date).

Comment: @WhatsThePoint that would return more than a single row per email, because all ID's are unique and IP's can also be non-equal for a single user email.

The reply from Mureinik and jophab works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Window functions to the rescue:

```
SELECT email, date, user_ip, id
FROM   (SELECT email, date, ip AS user_ip, logid AS id, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  ip IS NOT NULL) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**Note:** This query will retrieve exactly one row per unique email. If you want to support records tied for the max date, you should use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ranking Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql) available in sql server instead of `GROUP BY`.

One example is [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

```
;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS rn,
         email, 
         date,
         ip        AS User_IP,
         Logid     AS ID        
 FROM Table T WHERE (IP IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but what does the first line in the query?

;WITH CTE AS (

Comment: It is a common table expression read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

This will work great if you have an index on `Table(email, date)`

```
SELECT email  AS email,
  date        AS Date,
  ip          AS User_IP,
  Logid       AS ID
FROM Table
WHERE IP IS NOT NULL and 
      (email, date) = (
           SELECT email, Max(date) 
           FROM Table 
           GROUP BY email
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer,

```
SELECT L.email  AS email,
L.date      AS Date,
L.ip        AS User_IP,
L.Logid     AS ID
FROM Table AS T
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT email,MAX(Date)Date 
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY email) AND (IP IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY T.email
```

Hope this helps you.